# Freeform Pro form not appearing in channel entry

Tags: solspace-freeform

I'm using Freeform Pro and added a new form through the Composer, and then added the new form to a channel entry. After saving the channel entry, the form appears in the preview in the backend. However, when viewing the live site, the form does not appear.

Am I missing a step in the implementation that would cause this not to appear?

Comment: Please, add some template code to your question. Thanks!

Comment: Please, post the solution as an answer an mark it as right. To have unanswered question makes harder for us to find which ones still needs attention. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-reading the documentation, I was able to get this working using the following code:

```
{exp:channel:entries}{general-contact}{/exp:channel:entries}
```

{general-contact} is the Freeform channel field short name.